# Why does char pointer get a 32-bit value (ffffff88)

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, char, int

```
int in=0xeef01f88;
int * ipoi=&in;
char*cpoi=(char*)ipoi;
cout<<std::hex<<(int)*ipoi<<" "<<(int)*(cpoi)<<" "<<(int)*(cpoi+1)<<" "<<(int)*(cpoi+2)<<endl;
```

When I compile this on Cxxdroid (Android compiler) it works perfectly as it should so cout from char pointers gives values of separate bytes like:

```
eef01f88 88 1f f0.
```

Another way when I compile the same code on Windows using GNU GCC COMPILER I got this output:

```
eef01f88 ffffff88 1f fffffff0.
```

How is it possible? Why the first and third char pointer values has ffffff in themselves? There even aren't any ff values around `*(cpoi+1)`. (f0)
Will changing compiler fix the problem?

I am using Code Blocks. It has plenty of compiling options but I already tried every standard available (up to 2011 ISO C language standard). What am I missing?

Comment: Similar: [printf adds extra `FFFFFF` to hex print from a char array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31090616/995714)

Comment: int * to char *   Because both pointers can point to the same Byte in memory. And as you see both systems(android windows) have the same hierarchy of bits so the code should work the same. To make you believe its possible I even wrote the string of ints based on casts string <->int.

Comment: string potential_frames(char * source,long long length){
string str;
long long i;
  ...
char * i_c=(char*) &i;
str=str+*(i_c+3);
str=str+*(i_c+2);
str=str+*(i_c+1);
str=str+*(i_c);
return str;
}
  
  
int in=((int)i_str[n*4])*256*256*256+((int)i_str[n*4+1])*256*256+((int)i_str[n*4+2])*256+((int)i_str[n*4+3]);

It works on android perfectly.

Comment: Suggest adding a language tag. You mention ISO C in the question but the code sample `cout << std::hex` suggests you are attempting to use C++ (which is a different language to C)

Comment: Because (1) chars are signed, (2) 0x88 is negative, (3) char is promoted to `int`, and (4) that promotion is sign-extending.

Comment: I am using functions from both c and cpp. Sscanf, cout. Here is full code: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1py_4hUFxeNF2HuGWFWmNVFpoLtm548Vy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` is meant for storing characters, not numeric values, so they can be signed or unsigned depending on the implementation

- On ARM [`char` is usually an unsigned type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20576300/995714) because [it's more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6532932/995714), therefore casting `char` to `int` results in a zero extension
- On pretty much everywhere else `char` is a signed type by default, so those bytes will be signed extended to `int`. As 0x88 and 0xf0 are negative, they'll have one bits in the high part

The solution is to avoid `char` and use `signed char` or `unsigned char` instead, or work around by adding the option to change the signness of char (`-funsigned-char` in gcc). Or even better, use fixed-width types like `uint8_t` and `int8_t`

See

- [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/995714)
- [Why is 'char' signed by default in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17097537/995714)
- [What causes a char to be signed or unsigned when using gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46463064/995714)
- [Are characters signed or unsigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6971150/995714)
- [Difference between char and signed char in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16503373/995714)
- [Why don't the C or C++ standards explicitly define char as signed or unsigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15533115/995714)

Comment: Thanks. Did -funsigned-char. Seems to work fine. Had more issues thought. With strings. Had to add str.c_string() and also with binary. Had to change 0b values to dec/hex...

Comment: if it helps then kindly accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark. Note that there's no `c_string()` in `std::string`, only `c_str()`. And the signness of `char` is completely **irrelevant** to binary literals 0b... But as warned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46463173/995714) you should never use those options to change the signness of char. Use `uint8_t` or `unsigned char` explicitly

Comment: I tried converting some chars as unsigned but some functions dont want to take them. Something in fstream didnt want to let me go through. I still look for solution to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56719858/delete-crashes-program   entire code is here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1py_4hUFxeNF2HuGWFWmNVFpoLtm548Vy